# How do I recreate the db folder after having deleted it?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, migration, sinatra

In my sinatra+activerecord app, I initially created a db folder with the `bundle exec rake db:create_migration NAME=migration` command, but at some point lost track of it. How can I restore that folder with the migration file?

Comment: @tadman Yeah, I somehow lost it.

Comment: Github? or another source control programme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using git  or any other scm, there is no straitforward way to recover it.

But you can dump schema and then just load it.

```
mkdir db && touch db/schema.rb
rake db:schema:dump
```

Now you have db schema. Then you can just load it

```
rake db:schema:load
```